# Unicode emojis with colour

Tags: java, javafx, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to build a instant messaging application using JavaFX. I want to implement emoji support by using unicode however, when using a font such as Google's Noto Color Emoji the emoji's only appear as greyscale. like so:

[image: emojis]

I've applied the font like so and can confirm that it is loading correctly.

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Noto Color Emoji';
src: url('/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf');
}

.message-widget-font {
-fx-font-family: Noto Color Emoji;
}
```

Applying the CSS to the `Text` object:

```
messageText.getStyleClass().add("message-widget-font");
```

Is there a way to get the emoji's to have colour?

Comment: My guess is that you are going to have to come up with a solution that uses the PNGs or SVGs.

Comment: It's looking that way yeah, although I found a similar answer which stated all that was required was a font change such as "Noto Color Emoji"

Comment: I was reading this -> https://guigarage.com/2015/01/support-emojis/

Comment: Yeah I gave that a read also after applying the practices from that article I have the issue that I have now

Comment: My guess is that the text is not actually rendering in your desired font. Try simpler stripped-down experiment code. Perhaps your CSS is wrong or is being overridden. Or the font is not available, or is an old version lacking that glyph.

Comment: Do you mean something like [ _Speech Balloon_ or ️ _Left Speech Bubble_ or ️‍️ _Eye in Speech Bubble_](https://emojipedia.org/symbols/)?

Comment: It's the colour aspect i'm concerned with, as you can see from the image I supplied, the emojis are greyscale when they're supposed to have colour for example, smiley's should be yellow-filled etc.

Comment: Possibly relevant:  I have Noto Color Emoji installed, but `Font.getFamilies()` returns a list that does not include Noto Color Emoji.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried loading the font directly using `Font.loadFont()` and then going ahead with setting the font using `setFont()` however, this does not make a difference.

Comment: The Noto Color Emoji font doesn’t work in AWT, either.  Loading it with `Font.createFont` does work, and the resulting Font instance will return true from `canDisplay(0x1f600)`.  But using the Font results in nothing being drawn at all.